# How can i have a two sections in spinner item list, with different section header layout and items layout

Tags: android, spinner, dropdown

I want to show a drop down list which will show the list of cities. but i want to show separate sections for top five cities and rest of the other cities.
So, my first item in drop down list would be the header of first section i.e "Top cities" and next five row item would then show top 5 cities.
7th row would then show Header with title "Rest of the cities".

Im unable to find a solution for this, any guidance would be helpful. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following:

Create a Model class say `CustomSpinnerModel`

```
public class CustomSpinnerModel {
public String id;
public String name;
public boolean isSelected;
public int type;//for view type
}
```

Create custom spinner Adapter like this and override `getDropDownView`

```
    public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomSpinnerModel> {
                        private Context context;
                        private LayoutInflater inflater;
                        private ArrayList<CustomSpinnerModel> spinnerList;

                        public CustomSpinnerAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<CustomSpinnerModel> spinnerList) {
                            super(context, resource, spinnerList);
                            this.context = context;
                            this.spinnerList = spinnerList;
                            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                        }
                    }

     @Override 
     public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;

            //Get your model at position
        CustomSpinnerModel model = spinnerList.get(position);
        String type = model.type;

        //Based on type inflate the respective view
        switch(type){
        case "Top cities" : 
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_cities_header, parent, false);
        //Do your other operation such as setting text etc
        break;
        //other cases and operation.


        return view;
        }

    //other @Override methods

}
```